# Does Monitor.Enter() allow events to be processed if called on the UI thread of a C# application?

Tags: .net, locking

I'm investigating a stack trace (seen while debugging) that looks something like the following:

```
MyUtility.AcquireLock()
[some of our code]
MyControl.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
[some external WinForms (painting) code]
(native code corresponding to Monitor.Enter(object))
MyUtility.AcquireLock()
[some of our code]
MyControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

Does this make sense or did something screw up my stack trace?

I'm almost (but not completely) certain, no other thread is holding this lock, I'm trying to acquire (by using Monitor.Enter()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. Monitor.Enter does a so called alertable wait. Only few people know what this means in 2011 because it is an obscure concept. It means that the thread will pump window messages while waiting. Yes, this seems grotesque. You are currently in a very dark world of pain because you are facing nondeterministic reentrancy issues.

The way to the light is to not wait on the gui thread at all! Start a background thread, maybe a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Does `Wait` do the same thing?  Could one use a wait with a timeout as an alternative to `Sleep` if one wants to hit the message pump, and if enough controls are disabled to preclude accidental recursion?

Comment: @supercat supercat I don't know. I do not recommend waiting on the UI thread anyway. Even if it works due to pumping waiting it complicates application design due to reentrancy. Much better options are available (such as a simple worker thread, or async-await).

Comment: In some cases, the natural behavior for a button is to do a few operations on the UI thread with a little time between them [e.g. briefly highlight a control on the display, long enough to be visible].  Creating a background task for something that would then have to `BeginInvoke` the control on the UI thread to perform the visual update seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @supercat I strongly disagree. Today many easy techniques are available for this (for example async, Tasks an Invoke which is easier than BeginInvoke).

Comment: The scenario I described could be coded as `{LockUi(); BigButton.Color = Color.Green; UiSleep(100); BigButton.Color = Color.Red; UnlockUi();}` I'm not familiar with the techniques you describe, but I don't know how much easier they could be.